# Why is the cost price calculation even necessary for the given problem?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

Question:

" Baniya sells two types of tea viz. Desi Chai and Videshi Chai. He sells Desi Chai and Videshi Chai. He sells Desi Chai at 18 per kg and incurs a loss of 10 % whereas on selling the Videsi Chai at 30 per kg, he gains 20 %. In what proportion should the Desi Chai and Videshi Chai be mixed such that he can gain a profit of 25 % by selling the mixture at 27.5 per kg."

Doubt:

"Here the selling price is fixed in all cases. Then how does it even depend upon me to change the composition and arrive at the required values. I wonder why would mentioning the profit percent even be required. The selling doesn't change either way does it? I hope I am able to express myself about what I found weird in the question."

Comment: Questions that I think that you need to answer to solve the problem: [1] What is the cost in raw materials of each of the two types of teas?  For example, if $1.2 \times x = 30$, then what is $x$?  [2] If the price of $27.5$ represents a profit of $25$%, then what should be the cost in raw materials for the blend of two teas?  That is, if $a \times 1.25 = 27.5$, then what is $a$?  [3] Once you calculate the price in raw materials for each of the two teas, what proportion should they be blended so that the cost of the blend is as computed in [2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, that the price *at which* Baniya *sells* is fixed.  But the price Baniya *pays* in raw materials to produce his chai is not — it depends on what those raw ingredients are.  In particular, if Videshi Chai costs more, then using more Videshi Chai in his Milahwa Chai (mixed chai) causes the Milahwa Chai to cost more to make; conversely, if Videshi Chai is cheaper, then using more Videshi Chai makes the Milahwa Chai cheaper to make.

Your job is to determine the appropriate composition of raw materials to effect the desired profit.  Baniya's profit is the difference between the money he makes per kg and the price he paid for that original kg.

Ideally, that should be enough to get you started.